# Why does increasing the intensity of the B field increase the force on a current carrying wire?

Tags: electromagnetism

Why does increasing the magnetic field strength increase the force on a current carrying wire?- as outlined in the equation
F= BIL
where B is equal to the magnetic flux density around the wire
Thanks

Comment: It's a phenomenon seen in experiments, one of the foundations of electromagnetic theory. There is no "why".

Comment: What would you expect to happen instead? Or, put another way, what would it mean for the B field to be stronger, if it didn't change the force produced by that field on a moving charge (or the torque on a magnetic dipole)?

Comment: How it works see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/768047/why-do-magnetic-fields-induce-current-in-wires-when-the-electrons-in-the-wires-a